# Dexie -- TypeError: Cannot set property 'onerror' of undefined(…)

Tags: indexeddb, dexie

I am using Dexie in my offline application, and when I try to insert new Data in my Indexeddb database I get this error: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'onerror' of undefined(…)`

This is the code that seems to be throwing the error:

```
InsertApiLogs: function (Data) {
            return DB.transaction('rw', DB.ApiLogs, () => {
                DB.ApiLogs.clear().then(
                    DB.ApiLogs.bulkPut(Data)
                );
            }).catch( function (E) {
                console.log(E);
                return false;
            });
        },
```

This is where I create my Database:

```
var DB = new Dexie('local', {autoOpen: true});

DB.version(1).stores({
    Event: "EventId, Name, StartDate, EndDate, Description, OriginalUserId, DateCreated, IsArchived, IsRecurring, CreatedInGCal",
    Pipeline: "PipelineId, Name, Image, DateCreated, DateArchived, Statuses",
    ApiLogs: "APILogId, UserCode, FunctionName, Success, Error, Parameters, ReturnVal, Date",
    MySelf: "Type, Data"
});
```

Since I am adding tables as I go and I don't wanna create many versions of the database I did the following to clean up the DB:

```
var DB = new Dexie('local', {autoOpen: true});

DB.delete();

    DB.version(1).stores({
        Event: "EventId, Name, StartDate, EndDate, Description, OriginalUserId, DateCreated, IsArchived, IsRecurring, CreatedInGCal",
        Pipeline: "PipelineId, Name, Image, DateCreated, DateArchived, Statuses",
        ApiLogs: "APILogId, UserCode, FunctionName, Success, Error, Parameters, ReturnVal, Date",
        MySelf: "Type, Data"
    });
```

Then I deleted `DB.delete()` and reloaded. I am telling you this just in case that is not good practice and might have compromised my DB state.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The *then* handler of `DB.ApiLogs.clear()` is missing an arrow or function expression.

Answer (score 0):

Just since this is the top Google result:

This isn't the OP's issue, but for me, this somehow happened by passing `bulkAdd`/`bulkPut` bad data.

The API returned data in the form `{data: any[]}`; where `data` is an array of rows to add to IDB. I was passing this response directly to `bulkAdd` though:

```
const response = await apiCall();  // returns {data: [{}, {}]}
await dexie.table('a_table').bulkAdd(response);
```

What I should have had was:

```
await dexie.table('a_table').bulkAdd(response.data);
```

I have no idea how that possibly lead to that error, but I wanted to document this given how long it took me to figure out.